# Utility of standard matrix norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Just thought to myself that after all, $(M_n(\mathbb{R}),+,.)$ is conceptually the same $\mathbb{R}$-vector space as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, so the norm $\sqrt{tr(AA^*)}$ must be equivalent to all the usual  $p$-norms on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. So what makes it better ? Is it used on other spaces whose dimension is a perfect square ?

Comment: It is the Euclidean norm with all it's benefits

Comment: As in $tr(AA^*)=\Sigma_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2$ ?

Comment: Actually yes I see it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

It is consistent with the inner product $\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{tr} (AB^*) = \sum_{i,j} [A]_{ij} \overline{[B]}_{ij}$.

Comment: That kind of brings the question to "Why use that inner product instead of the one on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ ?" Which I now know is the same